# ArgumentError in RailsAdmin::Main#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

My code was working fine before i changed the names **hotel** to **system** and **room** to **pakage** in my entire code including model, table name, column name and row data. Now when i try to **add** or **edit** in my **brains** and **users** table in railsadmin it shows argumenterror.

[This error came when i try **add new** in brains table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38nwx.png)

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a problem with the word **System**. So I changed all the **System** to **Entity** and now it is working fine.